# running NN software with my own data

Tags: matlab, neural-network

New with Matlab.

When I try to load my own date using the NN pattern recognition app window, I can load the source data, but not the target (it is never on the drop down list).  Both source and target are in the same directory.  Source is 5000 observations with 400 vars per observation and target can take on 10 different values (recognizing digits).  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything with your own data you might want to try out the example data sets available in the toolbox. That should make many problems easier to find later on because they definitely work, so you can see what's wrong with your code.

Regarding your actual question: Without more details, e.g. what your matrices contain and what their dimensions are, it's hard to help you. In your case some of the problems mentioned here might be similar to yours:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/17531-problem-with-targets-in-nprtool

From what I understand about nprtool your targets **have to** consist of a matrix with only one 1 (for the correct class) in either row or column (depending on the input matrix), so make sure that's the case.